# send sms to multiple recipients

Tags: c#, sms-gateway

I am developing a small application to send SMS to mutiple users through Ozeki NG - SMS Gateway. I found a Windows application to send a sms to one recipient. But I want to send sms to multiple client using C# and a MySQL database.

I follow the following url.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20064/How-to-Send-SMS-Messages-from-C-using-an-SQL-Datab

Comment: So just run that code multiple times.

Comment: public static void SendSMS(string text,int phonenumber){/*Send the sms here*/}    and in your main method foreach (peron in persons) {SendSMS(mytext,person.Phonenumber);}

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this if you have an application.

I would also look to using a mobile aggregator and / or an SMS Gateway. e.g. [txtNation' SMS Gateway](http://gateway.txtnation.com/).

Also I would think about what you need the SMS Gateway for in the first instance and go from there.
Ask yourself how much thoughput you need, how many messags to send and what is your target price per SMS. What type of connection do you need - http, smpp ?